# CheckListBox in sessionState mode=InProc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need your help please,
I have a checkBoxList item stored in session that would tell me which items are selected and which are not, I do see the items but I don't know how to retrieve them. thanks you. check my code
Web.Config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"
```

UserObject

```
namespace UsertManagement.Web
  {
/// <summary>
/// Role element.
/// </summary>
[DataContract(Namespace = ServiceNamespaces.Common)]
[Serializable]
public class USERObject : ICloneable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets/gets checklist app.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public List<string > CheckListApp { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the copy of current object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public USERObject  Clone()
    {
        return new USERObject
        {
            CheckListApp = this.CheckListApp 
        };
    }
}
   }
```

how I stored the CheckListApp

```
USERObject userobject = new USERObject { CheckListApp = GetAppValues(true) };
```

getValues

```
 private List<string> GetAppValues(bool selected)
    {
    List<string> vName = CheckListApp.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected == selected).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

            return vName;
        }
```

Comment: You haven't stored anything in session in above code.

Comment: Did I forgot something ? thanks

Comment: `Session["key"] = <value>`

Comment: I don't have Session keyword, I got SessionStateMode, SessionStateParameter, SessionStateAction...and I have referenced using System.Web.SessionState; is it because I'm not using System.Web.UI.Page ? thanks

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session`